# UIScrollView with UIImageView partially visible on screen

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView with a UIImageView in order to enable zoom features.

The problem now is that the scrollView should be shown fullscreen (except the navigationBar), but it's shown with a weird "offset".

Due that images explains more than 1000 words, here it is:
[image]

The red rectangles are the weird offset that's being shown, while the image should take the whole view, but it's not. As you see,it's being cut instead.

I tried changing the frame, bounds etc but same result.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];

    imageScrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
    imageScrollView.delegate = self;
    imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = NO; // If set to yes, the image would be like the screen above
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;


    imageScrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);

    //activity indicator
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.frame.size.width /2, self.imageView.frame.size.height/2);
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];


    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tipImageString]
              placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                       success:^(UIImage *image) { [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }
                       failure:^(NSError *error) {  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }];
    [imageView addSubview:activityIndicator];

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
    imageView.center = [[imageScrollView window] center];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageScrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    imageScrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;    
    imageScrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

    CGSize boundsSize = self.imageScrollView.bounds.size;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    CGRect frameToCenter = imageView.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    imageView.frame = frameToCenter;

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = 0.50;//[imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;
    imageScrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;
    [imageScrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView sizeToFit];

    [imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

}
```

I tried everything, but with no success!

I think that's something with frames but i can't figure out what.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pheel Glad that you find it due to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` of the image. This may change the coordinates.

Comment: Indeed. I had to set the imageScrollView frame again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Image Resolution. Also, did you try visually placing the scroll view and then placing the image view in Interface Builder. After doing that, you can initialize it in a method such as ViewDidLoad

Comment: Tried with several images (even lower resolution), same results. Yep, everything connected in IB, no enhancements.

Comment: how about the attributes inspector?

Comment: Everything is fine, the scrollView is set to be shown full-screen (whole view)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
... set-up imageView...
imageView.frame = imageScrollView.bounds;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

You have a lot of code that is redundant or have cumulative effect in your method (multiple consecutive changes of frame/center, contentMode, contentSize...), which makes it hard to know what is causing what (probably the scroll view is clipping the image view, whose center is first based on the window coordinate instead of its superview coordinates, but finally not, because you redefine its frame...). You should probably start from scratch with some simpler code, depending on what you want exactly, and the configuration you start with (what is the scroll view frame for instance?).

Comment: Well i took the code from my other project where it was working perfectly. I don't really know why now it's not working (or better, it is but not as in the old project). I'll try to do what you did, but there are some adjustments in the code that makes the image be at the perfect center of the view (i.e.)